# Why am I getting request method GET not supported?

Tags: rest, http, post, cisco, postman

I am using PostMan as a REST client to test this API method [Cisco ACL Analysis API](https://developer.cisco.com/media/apicem_reference_guide/index.html#!/acl/getAclTracksStd). specifically POST /acl/trace or getAClTracksStd (first go to Policy Analysis)

Here is my PostMan HTTP test call[image]

Does anyone who is familiar with PostMan understand why I am getting this "Request method 'GET' is not supported" error from the server? I am making a POST HTTP request, not GET.(Selected from Drop down menu) It make more sense for me to get a input invalid parameter error or something.

Just to show that the endpoint url works, heres a HTTP test request that works
[image](same link, host->host API -> GET /host/{startIndex}/{recordsToReturn}

Comment: check the postman console, there may be a redirection

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's two issues that I'm seeing with your REST call.  First, the error you're seeing is because the call needs to be preceded by "https://".  Second, remove the interface IDs parameter and values.  You should get a response with data after making these changes.

Comment: Thank you! my {{baseUrl}} variable I imported from a Swagger file had the base url set to `//www.myapi...`.  Changing it to `https://www.myapi...` fixed the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Your json looks erronuous (comma after the destIp) - and the server probably always responds with a default confusing error message in this case. (Postman is very well tested and it sends POST).

Comment: Thanks added the comma, didn't make a difference. Do you think this is a server side issue then?

Comment: Yes, the result is from the server; to double-check you can use other network tools (Fiddler.Net, WireShark) or play around with the json to make the result proper. Something with it isn't write.