# Spring Boot Security 403 "Access Denied"

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-security, postman

I am making a RESTFul API (not web-app) and adding Spring Security but unable to do it successfully.

After going through a lot of articles and posts here on ***stackoverflow***, I am finally posting my question. Kindly go through it and let me know what I am missing  or configuring wrongly?

**Base Entity**

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long ID;

    @CreatedBy
    @Column(name = "CreatedBy", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private String createdBy;

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "CreatedDate", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;

    @LastModifiedBy
    @Column(name = "ModifiedBy")
    private String modifiedBy;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "ModifiedDate")
    private LocalDateTime modifiedDate;

    ...getters setters
}
```

**Role Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ROLE")
public class Role extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String name;

    ...getters setters
}
```

**User Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "EmiratesID", unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private String emiratesID;

    @Column(name = "FirstName")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LastName")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "StaffID", unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private String staffID;

    @Column(name = "Email", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "Password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID")
    private Role role;

    ...getters setters

    public UserDetails currentUserDetails() {
        return CurrentUserDetails.create(this);
    }

}
```

**SecurtiyConfig Class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final DataSource dataSource;
    private final UserDetailsServiceImplementation userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(final DataSource dataSource, final UserDetailsServiceImplementation userDetailsService) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;

    }

    @Bean
    BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/console/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/", "/greetUser", "/register", "/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyAuthority(ROLES.USER.getValue(), ROLES.ADMIN.getValue())
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority(ROLES.ADMIN.getValue()).anyRequest().authenticated();
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable();

        // required to make H2 console work with Spring Security
        httpSecurity.headers().frameOptions().disable();

    }

    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) {

        webSecurity.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**");
    }
```

**CurrentUserDetails**

```
public class CurrentUserDetails implements UserDetails {

    private String ROLE_PREFIX = "ROLE_";

    private Long userID;
    private String emiratesID;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String staffID;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private Role role;

    public CurrentUserDetails(Long ID, String emiratesID, String firstName,
                              String lastName, String staffID, String email,
                              String password, Role role) {

        super();
        this.userID = ID;
        this.emiratesID = emiratesID;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.staffID = staffID;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.role = role;

    }

    public Long getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public String getEmiratesID() {
        return emiratesID;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public Role getRole() {
        return this.role;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthority = new ArrayList<>();

        grantedAuthority.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(ROLE_PREFIX + role.getName()));

        return grantedAuthority;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return this.email;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Helper method to add all details of Current User into Security User Object
     * @param user User
     * @return UserDetails
     */
    public static UserDetails create(User user) {
        return new CurrentUserDetails(user.getID(), user.getEmiratesID(),
                                      user.getFirstName(), user.getLastName(),
                                      user.getStaffID(), user.getEmail(),
                                      user.getPassword(), user.getRole());
    }

}
```

**UserDetailsService**

```
@Component/@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImplementation implements UserDetailsService {

    private static final Logger userDetailsServiceImplementationLogger = LogManager.getLogger(UserDetailsServiceImplementation.class);
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserDetailsServiceImplementation(final UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(username)) {
            userDetailsServiceImplementationLogger.error("UserDetailsServiceImplementation.loadUserByUsername() :: FAILED");

            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("UserName is not passed");
        }

        User userFound = userRepository.findByEmail(username);

        if (userFound == null) {
            userDetailsServiceImplementationLogger.error("No user found with given username = {}", username);

            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No user found with given username");
        }

        return userFound.currentUserDetails();
    }

}
```

**UserController Class**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/user")
public class UserController {

    private static Logger userControllerLogger = LogManager.getLogger(UserController.class);

    @Autowired
    private PropertiesConfig propertiesConfig;

    @Autowired
    private UserManager userManager;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/listAll", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> getUsersList() {
        userControllerLogger.info("UserController.getUsersList()[/listAll] :: method call ---- STARTS");

        LinkedHashMap<String, Object> result = userManager.findAllUsers();

        userControllerLogger.info("UserController.getUsersList()[/listAll] :: method call ---- ENDS");

        return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

**AdminContrller Class**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin")
public class AdminController {

    private static final Logger adminControllerLogger = LogManager.getLogger(AdminController.class);

    private final PropertiesConfig propertiesConfig;
    private final UserManager userManager;

    @Autowired
    public AdminController(final PropertiesConfig propertiesConfig, final UserManager userManager) {
        this.propertiesConfig = propertiesConfig;
        this.userManager = userManager;

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = {RequestMethod.GET})
    public ResponseEntity<String> adminPortal(@RequestBody String adminName) {
        adminControllerLogger.info("AdminController.adminPortal()[/home] :: method call ---- STARTS");

        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        UserDTO adminUser = userManager.findUserByEmail(auth.getName());

        if (adminUser == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(propertiesConfig.getProperty(ApplicationProperties.Messages.NO_USER_FOUND.getValue()));
        }

        adminControllerLogger.info("AdminController.adminPortal()[/home] :: method call ---- ENDS");

        return new ResponseEntity<>(ApplicationConstants.GeneralConstants.WELCOME.getValue() + adminUser.getStaffID(), HttpStatus.OK);

    }

}
```

**data.sql**

Tried with both values ***ROLE_USER***/***ADMIN*** and ***USER***/***ADMIN***

```
INSERT INTO ROLE(ID, CreatedBy, CreatedDate, ModifiedBy, ModifiedDate, Name) VALUES (-100, 'Muhammad Faisal Hyder', now(), '', null, 'ROLE_ADMIN'/'ADMIN')
INSERT INTO ROLE(ID, CreatedBy, CreatedDate, ModifiedBy, ModifiedDate, Name) VALUES (-101, 'Muhammad Faisal Hyder', now(), '', null, 'ROLE_USER'/'USER')

INSERT INTO USER(ID, CreatedBy, CreatedDate, ModifiedBy, ModifiedDate, EmiratesID, FirstName, LastName, Email, StaffID, Password, ROLE_ID) VALUES (-1, 'Muhammad Faisal Hyder', now(), '', null, 'ABCDEF12345', 'Muhammad Faisal', 'Hyder', 'faisal.hyder@gmail.com', 'S776781', '$2a$10$qr.SAgYewyCOh6gFGutaWOQcCYMFqSSpbVZo.oqsc428xpwoliu7C', -100)
INSERT INTO USER(ID, CreatedBy, CreatedDate, ModifiedBy, ModifiedDate, EmiratesID, FirstName, LastName, Email, StaffID, Password, ROLE_ID) VALUES (-2, 'Muhammad Faisal Hyder', now(), '', null, 'BCDEFG12345', 'John', 'Smith', 'John.Smith@gmail.com', 'S776741', '$2a$10$j9IjidIgwDfNGjNi8UhxAeLuoO8qgr/UH9W9.LmWJd/ohynhI7UJO', -101)
```

I have attached all possible classes I think which are necessary. Kindly let me know what can be the issue.

Articles I went through;
[SO-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37615034/spring-security-spring-boot-how-to-set-roles-for-users), [SO-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49897276/spring-security-antmatcher-is-not-working), [SO-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746466/spring-security-always-returns-http-403), [SO-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29980675/why-am-i-getting-request-method-get-not-supported), [Article-1](https://medium.com/@gustavo.ponce.ch/spring-boot-spring-mvc-spring-security-mysql-a5d8545d837d), [Article-2](https://www.javainuse.com/spring/boot_security_jdbc_authentication)

[image: POST Man]

**Resolved**

@dur thanks to you for pointing it out and others as well for their helpful insights.

```
1- Use ROLE_ in db entries.
2- Once prefix is added in db then no need to explicitly add this in
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(){...}
3- .and().httpBasic(); was missing from SpringSecurity configuration.
4- This is very detailed, might be helpful to others as well.
```

Comment: Can you try changing line `.antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority(ROLES.ADMIN.getValue()).anyRequest().authenticated();`
to 
`.antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN").anyRequest().authenticated();` ?

Comment: @AvijitBarua buddy, already tried it. Also added both ADMIN. ROLE_ADMIN in grantedAuthorities while overriding it. Tried both way in DB ADMIN, and ROLE_ADMIN. Nothing works. I am thinking in security description I need to tell security which field name to expect for username. BTW, when we use hasAuthority instead of hasRole, Spring adds ROLE_ prefix itself.

Comment: While overriding userName in UserDetails I am returning email, so username should be expected as email...

Comment: @dur 1st- I tried with both ADMIN/ROLE_ADMIN in sql.
2nd- I used both ROLE_ and without in GrantedAuthority.
3rd- I attached picture of req/res based on the created user, not the one already delcared in SQL.
4th- Issue might be I was not declaring httpBasic(). I solved it now.
5th- hasAuthority needs ROLE_ADMIN/USER because spring automatically adds it in GrantedAuthority.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @dur pointed out in comments, I am adding answer to my question.

```
1- Use ROLE_ in db entries.
2- Once prefix is added in db then no need to explicitly add this in
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(){...}
3- .and().httpBasic(); was missing from SpringSecurity configuration.
```

Since this post is very detailed, might be helpful to others as well. For corrected answer kindly refer to my [git repo](https://github.com/MFaisalHyder/spring-boot-app)

Answer (score 0):

The problem I'm seeing is that you're granting access for authority `ADMIN` but you're not adding this authority to the `CurrentUserDetails`, you're just adding their role. You should add the authority as well, i.e.

```
@Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthority = new ArrayList<>();

        grantedAuthority.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(ROLE_PREFIX + role.getName()));

        // add authority in addition to role (no role prefix)
        grantedAuthority.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));

        return grantedAuthority;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering @msparer, I also searched that and found when we use .hasAuthority we don't need to check for Prefix it is automatically added. so for granting authority I explicitly added it as I am overriding it.

Comment: Still the same, 403.
I am using H2, I already added few statements in data.sql. Entries are perfectly fine, even user is registered properly. but using that user/admin for querying respective resource, it screams 403 :/
One potential issue I think is that I am not telling SecurityConfig which field to expect to be passed and used a "username" but if i do that then it will be form based login, and when I do that It gives GET method not supported...

Comment: While overriding userName in UserDetails I am returning email, so username should be expected as email...